# Is there a way to automatically/programatically export cookies from Chrome on Windows 10?

Tags: python, powershell, google-chrome, cookies, windows-10

Chrome cookies are stored under `C:\Users\<your_username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cookies` but they are in an encrypted SQLite database file.

Is there any way to access the cookies without going through Chrome itself? Or, failing that, to automate Chrome exporting the plaintext cookies for you.

I need to get the cookies for a domain automatically saved in a certain directory on a regular schedule. I can use powershell/batch or python to do this.

I found [this script](https://pastebin.com/gxKHDQty) that works for Firefox on Linux:

Is it at all possible on Windows with Chrome given the file is encrypted. I'm aware of various extensions that allow you to save cookies for a domain as plaintext but this must be done manually - I want a scriptable solution.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have no idea how to decrypt the file so not much.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a Windows computer at hand, but would this work ?

```py
import sqlite3

import win32crypt  # obtained from `pip install pywin32`

cookies_filepath = '...'  # <--- CHANGE ME

with sqlite3.connect(cookies_filepath) as connection:
    result = connection.execute('select host_key, name, encrypted_value from cookies')  # add other fields if you want
    for host_key, name, encrypted_value in result:
        # see http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32crypt__CryptUnprotectData_meth.html
        crypt_description, value = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(encrypted_value, None, None, None, 0)
        print(f"{host_key!r} {name!r} {value!r}")
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm afraid I'm getting the following error:   File "D:\Downloads\chromecookies.py", line 5
    cookies_filepath = "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1\Cookies"  # <--- CHANGE ME
                      ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: @Turkeyphant add a `r` before the string, like so : `cookies_filepath = r'...'`.

Comment: Thanks. Now I get crypt_description, value = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(encrypted_value, None, None, None, 0)
pywintypes.error: (87, 'CryptProtectData', 'The parameter is incorrect.')

Comment: @Turkeyphant see https://stackoverflow.com/q/60329372/11384184

Comment: thanks I already saw that page but I'm afraid I don't understand what I need to do to correct this error.